# Xcode cocoa osx NSTextfield query

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, display

I created a simple maths based app. The app asks a user 6 multiplication table questions. e.g. Q1 10 x 10
The user enters an answer
The app displays whether the user's answer was correct or incorrect and displays this using the following

```
IBOutlet NSTextField *CorrectIncorrect;
```

In a cycle of the app (1 question of 6) CorrectIncorrect is used to display the strings 'correct' or 'incorrect' using this line of code

```
[CorrectIncorrect setStringValue:receivedAnswer];
[[CorrectIncorrect window] display];
```

Then as the next question is posed to the user, the either string is cleared using the following code.

```
[CorrectIncorrect setStringValue:@""];
[[CorrectIncorrect window] display];
```

Initially, each CorrectIncorrect string was being cleared to quickly, so the user never saw if their answer was 'correct' or 'incorrect'.  I therefore used a time delay method to slow the process in order to allow the user to see the display before it was cleared.see below

```
- (void)TimeDelay
{
    startInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    stopInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    while ((stopInterval - startInterval) <= 1)
    {

    stopInterval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    }
}
```

This worked fine in Xcode 5. Does not work in Xcode 7.3.1. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `[[CorrectIncorrect window] display];` should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1) Time interval is in seconds, so `<= 1` really isn't much time, have you tried increasing that time and seeing what it looks like?

2) You should also consider adding a button like "Go to next question".  That way you won't need to have a timer

3) If you want to have a timer to reset the string, you should just use Grand Central Dispatch

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [CorrectIncorrect setStringValue:@""];
});
```

one-ish line, and is more intuitive

Comment: 3) or without Grand Central Dispatch: `[CorrectIncorrect performSelector:@selector(setStringValue:) withObject:@"" afterDelay:10.0];`

Comment: Many thanks for the useful suggestion and the solutions both work. Great!